# gensim w2k - additional file

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I trained w2v on rather big (> 200 million sentences) corpus, and got, in addition to file w2v_model.model, files: w2v_model.model.trainables.syn1neg.npy and w2v.model_model.wv.vectors.npy. Model file was successfully loaded and read all npy files without any exceptions. The obtained model performed OK.

Now I retrained the model on much bigger corpus (> 1 billion sentences). The same 3 files were automatically saved, as expected.

When I try to load my new retrained model:

```
w2v_model = Word2Vec.load(path_filename)
```

I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/...../w2v_US.model.trainables.vectors_lockf.npy'
```

But no .npy file with such extension was saved by gensim at the end of the training
(I save all output files in the same library, as required).

What should I do to obtain such file as a part of output .npy files (may be some option in  gensim w2v when training)? May be there are other ways to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `.save()` is creating any files with the word `trainables` in it, you're using a older version fo Gensim. Any new training should definitely prefer using a current version. As of now (January 2022), that's `gensim-4.1.2`, released 2021-09.

If an attempt at a `.load()` generated that particular error, then there should've been that file, alongside the others you mention, created when the `.save()` had been done. (In fact, the only way that the *main* file you named with `path_filename` should be able to know that *other* filename is if that other file was written successfully, allowing the main file to complete writing.)

Are you sure that file wasn't written, but then somehow left behind, perhaps getting deleted or not moving alongside the other few files to some new filesystem path?

In general, I would suggest:

- using latest Gensim for any new training
- always enable Python logging at the INFO level, & watch the logging/console output of training/saving processes closely to see confirmation of expected activity/steps
- keep all files from a `.save()` that begin with the same main filename (in your examples above, `w2v_US.model`) together - & keep in mind that for larger models it may be a larger roster of files than for a small test model

You will probably have to re-train the model, but you *might* be able to re-generate a compatible `lockf` file via steps like the following:

- save aside all files of any potential use
- from the exact same configuration as your original `.save()` – including the same outdated Gensim version, exact same model parameters, & exact same training corpus – repeat all the model-building steps you did before up through the `.build_vocab()` step. (That is: no extra need to `.train()`.) This will create an *untrained* dummy model that should exactly match the vocabulary 'shape' of your broken model.
- use `.save()` to save *that* dummy model again - watching the logs/output for errors. There should be, alongside the other files, a file with a name like `dummy.model.trainables.vectors_lockf.npy`. If so, you *might* be able to copy that away, rename it to tbe the file expected by the original model whose load failed, then leave it alongside that original model - and the `.load()` might then succeed, or fail in a different way.

(If there were other problems/corruption at the time of the original model creation, this might not work. In particular, I wonder if when you talk about retraining the model, you didn't start with a fresh `Word2Vec` instance, but somehow expanded the older one, which might've added other problems/complications. In that case, a full retraining, ideally in the latest Gensim, would be necessary, and also a better basis for going forward.)